# How to scale page size down in Adobe Acrobat X Pro?

Tags: windows-7, scanning, adobe-acrobat, scaling

I scanned a document on a scanner at a friend's house and the pdf ended up being 35 inches by 45 inches in size.  I think this the cause of the trouble had for the person I sent it to, they get the error "insufficient image".

How can I scale this down in Adobe Acrobat X Pro to a normal 8.5x11 inch sheet so that I can see if that resolves their issue and I can share the document with them.  I cannot rescan the document, as I no longer have it.

Acrobat is running on Windows 7 OS. The scanner was an HP OfficeJet Pro L7650 All-in-one.

Comment: Please provide your operating system and scanner model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have Adobe Acrobat X Professional, you should be able to use the "Print to PDF" option.

All you would need to do is "Print to PDF," and make sure that the paper being printed to is letter format (8.5" x 11"). Page scaling options should be under the printer setup menu in the print dialog.

Comment: No dice due to encryption:
%%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
This PostScript file was created from an encrypted PDF file.
Redistilling encrypted PDF is not permitted.
%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%

Comment: @WilliamKF If you are not hesitant to install another program onto your computer, look into the following option through ElcomSoft: [link](http://www.elcomsoft.com/apdfpr.html) The free trial will decrypt the first four pages of a document. Again, as I am not sure that this PDF has a password/certificate associated with encryption, you should be able to use ElcomSoft's APDFPR software.

Answer (score 1):

Tools: Print Production: Set Page Boxes - Allows you to resize the entire document to whatever dimension you like using the bottom portion OR crop the page using the top portion of the "Set Page Boxes" area.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office installed, and you have an XPS printer installed, you should be able to print the PDF to the XPS printer.  If you want to retain the image quality, go into the XPS printer settings and choose PNG - lossless.  Then right click over the XPS file and convert it back into a PDF.  You can pick the page size then (8.5" x 11"), so the resulting PDF will already be sized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Adobe acrobat X:

1. Open your (.Pdf)-Document
2. Go to [file] > [Print]. See [Figure_1]
3. Choose as Printer [Adobe PDF] - Leave the configuration as it is. See [Figure_2]
4. Select [Page set up]. See [Figure_2]
5. Choose paper size see [Figure_3]

PS. I prepared a tutorial, but it's subordinated to a: "need at least 10 reputation to post images". So i was not allowed to post that Image-Tutorial.
Sorry.

Ajamun

Comment: You can post links to the images here and I'll embed them for you.